# Is there a way to differentiate between native and scanned pdf?

Tags: pdf

I am using ocr techniques to extract text from a pdf containing images, but I only want to use ocr if a pdf is not already searchable otherwise I want to use pdfminer or similar libraries.

Is there a way to differentiate between pdfs that are already searchable and pdfs that aren't?

Comment: There is not only black and white, there also are stages in-between. E.g. there may be pdfs with a mix of scans and "native" contents like scans if historical documents plus explanations. Or a scanner might have added "native" page numbers on pages with scans. And there may be scanned pdfs which have already been subject to ocr and, therefore, gotten a text layer of probably acceptable quality. Where do you want to draw the line?

Comment: At this stage I only want to distinguish between a native PDF totally with no other complexion and any other which is not a native 100% PDF

Comment: So you actually only want to check whether the page contains any bitmap images or not?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear 'Native PDF' isn't really a term from the PDF standard, I've seen some people use it to mean a PDF created directly in PDF authoring software so you have things like text and vector graphics in it for example.

It's really going to depend on what you *know* about the source PDF documents you are receiving.  For example if you know all Native PDFs will always consist of text then you could simply extract text from the document and if you find any consider it Native and otherwise consider it Scanned.

If you know all Scanned PDFs will always consist of images of a certain size and a certain compression then you could check for those attributes in the document and classify it accordingly.

Things become more complicated if you know nothing of the source input at all.  You could look at things like metadata as well and look for example for keywords that identify one versus the other.

Ultimately if you have some constraints on the type of input to expect the classification is pretty simple.

A good follow-up question is why you need to differentiate documents in this manner?  If we knew a bit about this maybe we could comment on the approach.